# ASRock Z97 Extreme4 Dr Debug Code 10

Tags: motherboard, bios

I have a motherboard which stopped working. It is plugged into a good power supply, the CPU has been checked for connections, and the RAM works fine in an identical MB.  But when I start this, I get Dr Debug code 10 immediately.

I have two PCs with the same build.  So I'm trying to see if the good machine can get code 10, but I cannot, no matter what I unplug.

I swapped power supplies, no difference.

Each has 8GB RAM set into A2 and B2. The RAM is Ballistix Sort VLP 160MHz.

I took the ram from the bad machine and put it in the good machine.  That machine then worked fine.  If I take all RAM out of the good machine I get code 53 - memory issue.  If I put one stick into A2 I get code A6 - because I unplugged the SATA drives. SO I cannot reproduce the issue by swapping RAM - I've swapped a number of times with the bad machine, and it still gives onyl code 10.

So it seems that the RAM is not the issue, since I can more any of the RAM into the good machine, with the same MB and PSU, and it gets well past the 10 code.

I tried switching from BIOS A to B, but still get 10.  I've pressed the Clear CMOS button.  I've also used the CMOS jumper to  clear it.  None of these move it from Code 10.

I've opened up the CPU, took it out, put it back.  Same code 10.
I then swapped CPU between machines. The good machine remained good, the bad remained code 10.

I swapped the CR2032 CMOS batteries, and same results.

At this point, is there anything to do other than to get a new motherboard?

Comment: Code 10 is a RAM error. Try with 1 RAM module (try different ones). Probably a RAM module is defect... Let us know if this works out.

Comment: Updating with RAM tests

Comment: I wound up getting a new motherboard.  An MSI Z97 PC Mate for $139 on NewEgg.  It works fine, and I did see a number of reviews about the ASUS failing.  Not a satisfactory solution, but ok enough.